# How to append text from same article into one string? Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, append

I have been learning Python for a month so I have a very basic understanding of  it. Beautifulsoup is even newer to me. I am attempting to download all relevant text from 250k articles from the kaggle US gun violence data set. With a small testing set I've managed to extract most of the relevant content. My problem is that when I try to save this text to a list, each "p" value turns into its own string. Hence I cannot distinguish which strings are from which articles. I would like a format where the text from each article is contained in one string and each new string is text from the next article.

Here's my code as far as I have made it:

```
dirty_text = []
for url in test_links:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    for node in soup.find_all('p'):
            dirty_text.append((node.get_text()))
```

I would provide the links, but I think this question is answerable with any arbitrary set of URL's. Any and all help appreciated! Also please correct me if I am going about using BeautifulSoup in a very wrong way. I did only start learning it today!

Comment: Why not make `dirty_text` a dict instead of a list of strings?  The key could be the URL and the value could be the text, so you'd be able to distinguish them that way.

Comment: @n1c9 I guess that's exactly what I was looking for. The only problem with the code that you provided is that it no longer returns all of the text, but rather only one sentence (a title or privacy policy) from each article. Any ideas on why that would be the case?

Comment: Fixed that up !

Comment: That works beautifully! Unfortunately I have a feeling that given my 200k + sources for articles, not all will have h1 as titles, so I will not be able to use that additional info provided. For the rest though, works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear it. If my answer helped, please consider giving it the green check mark and an up vote. :-)

Comment: Yes! Checked. Still not enough reputation for an up vote though, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding upon my comment, you'd be able to accomplish being able to distinguish between which link produced which text by re-writing to something like this:

```
dirty_text = {}
for url in test_links:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    dirty_text[url] = '\n'.join([node.get_text() for node in soup.find_all('p')])
```

Going further, if all the titles for the articles are formatted similarly (say they're all in the first h1 tag on the page), you could do something like this:

```
dirty_text = {}
for url in test_links:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    article_title = soup.find('h1').text
    dirty_text[article_title] = '\n'.join([node.get_text() for node in soup.find_all('p')])
```